# how to add parentheses and single quotes to bash string

Tags: mysql, string, bash

EDITED

I am trying to make some inserts in my mysql data base from a bash script. In this data base there are some varchar type arguments so I have to quote them when I make the query

I execute the query this way

`mysql --user=**** --password=**** -e $ext dbname`

I want to introduce in $ext the next text: `insert into tname (string,int) values ('$var',$ivar)`

The problem is that when I am trying to insert the parenthesis and the "'" they only put in the start of the string.

after I failed putting the example I will post parts of the code:
I get the datas from a file and store all the lines in myarray;

```
while IFS=$'\n' read -r line_data; do
myarray[i]="${line_data]"
((++i))
done < file.txt
```

and then in other while

```
somevar=${myarray[i++]}
var="'$somevar'"
echo $somevar
echo $var
```

Result:

```
Hello
'Hello
```

Comment: `$somevar="x"` is not bash syntax. This is not perl, thank you. When you use the right assignment syntax it should work.

Comment: And that correct syntax would be `var='value'`. Notice, no `$`, that is used when referencing the variable.

Comment: 4ae1e1 true in fact I dont do that exacly, I will correct it now, thx

Comment: Can you show the actual code, or as close as you can. The question is disjointed and unclear

Comment: @HashSu and Ashish Guys, please stop suggesting wrong things. If you don't know which characters need to be quoted, just RTFM https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes.

Comment: Ripe candidate for SQL injection: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: How is `myarray` populated? It looks like `somevar` has a carriage return at the end (`'Hello\r'`), which when printed would give you the output you observe.

Comment: @chpener i have think about that, i will post now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @chepner have said it is becouse at getting the string it was a \r character at end of all strings so that strange thing happens

Delete the las character of all the strings

```
var=${myarray[i++]}
var=${var::-1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your assignment syntax is incorrect. The `$` is only used when referring to the variable, not when assigning it a value. Fix your assignment and it should work fine:

```
$ var=foo
$ ivar=23
$ ext="insert into tname (string,int) values ('$var',$ivar)"
$ echo $ext
insert into tname (string,int) values ('foo',23)
```

Now you can use it in your command like this:

```
mysql --user=**** --password=**** -e "$ext" dbname
```

There are a number of ways this could go wrong, depending on what characters are in the data you're trying to insert, and it might be easier to write to a file instead of a variable.

Comment: this is what i tryed when i started with this, but dont work like that, still dont know why

Comment: @ainhoasayans The value of `ext` is correct, but you need to quote its expansion in the actual call. `mysql --user=**** --password=**** -e "$ext" dbname`, so that the entire string is passed literally as the single argument of the `-e` option.

Comment: @chepner true, i will do that, but the problem is that the value of $ext in my case is not correct